# Is function pointer address always static?

Tags: c, function, pointers

If a function pointer scopes out before being used in another thread to run, will the pointer be invalid? Or are function pointers always valid since they point to executable code which doesn't "move around"?

I think my real question is whether what the pointer points to (the function) will ever change, or is that value static throughout lifetime of program

Pseudo-code:

```
static void func(void) { printf("hi\n"); }

int main(void)
{
    start_thread();
    {
        void (*f)(void) = func;
        // edit: void run_on_other_thread(void (*f)(void));
        run_on_other_thread(f); // non-blocking. 
    }
    join_thread();
}
```

Comment: You want to check if `run_on_other_thread` takes a **copy** of that pointer, or a **reference**.  References can dangle, copies don't.

Comment: You seem to be mixing pointer object itself with the value (address) stored in that pointer.The address of `func` is always valid, regardless of whether `f` is still alive. If `run_on_other_thread` does not grab and store a *reference* to `f`, your code is fine. But you failed to provide any details about `run_on_other_thread`.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @DrewDormann — there’s nothing special about a pointer-to-function here. `f` goes out of scope, so its contents become invalid. If you called a function that copied the value everything is fine. If not, not.

Comment: This seems to be the same as asking whether after `int f = 4;` goes out of scope, I can no longer use the value 4. Storing a pointer to some object (whether it is a function or an integer) has no impact whatsoever on the object being pointed at. Objects don't vanish or jump around just because a pointer to them goes away.

Comment: I've edited it to show that the function does copy the pointer - I think my real question is whether what the pointer points to (the function) will ever change, or is that value static throughout lifetime of program

Comment: In the ordinary course of events, the value stored in `f` and passed to `run_on_other_thread()` won't change.  About the only possible exception would be along the lines of a dynamically loaded function (from a shared library) which is subsequently unloaded.  Then the pointer ceases to be valid — probably — and could end up pointing to other code if another shared library is dynamically loaded over the same part of the address space.  But this is fairly obscure (at best) and you don't need to worry about it, I think.

Comment: Or, let's put it this way: addresses of objects and functions never change in *their* lifetime.

Comment: OT Staates: "I think my real question is whether what the pointer points to (the function) will ever change", therefore the address of a function in memory, and this is not subject to the lifetime of a variable like `f`.

Answer (score 1):

In the C base language, the values of function pointers never become invalid. They point to functions, and functions exist for the entire time a program is executing. The value of a pointer is valid for the entire program.

An object that contains a pointer may have a limited lifetime. (Note: The question mentioned *scope*, but *scope* is **where** in the source code an identifier is visible. *Lifetime* is **when** during program execution an object exists.) In the question `void (*f)(void) = func;`, `f` is an object with automatic storage duration. Once execution of the block it is defined in ends, `f` no longer exists, and references to it have undefined behavior. However, the **value** that was assigned to `f` is still a valid value. For example, if we define `int x = 37;`, and the lifetime of `x` ends, that does not mean you can no longer use the value 37 in a program. In this case, the value that `f` had, which is the address of `func`, is still valid. The address of `func` can continue to be used throughout the program’s execution.

The situations discussed in [Xypron’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50780989/298225) regarding dynamically linked functions or dynamically created functions would be extensions to the C language. In these situations, it is not the lifetime of the pointer object that is in question but rather the fact that the function itself is being removed from memory that causes the pointer to be no longer a valid pointer to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a function pointer remains valid depends on its usage.

If it points to a function in the source code of your process it stays valid during the runtime of the process.

If you use a function pointer to point to a function in a dynamic link library, the pointer becomes invalid  when unloading the library.

Code can be written that relocates itself. E.g. when the Linux kernel is started it relocates itself changing the addresses of functions.

You could call a runtime compiler which creates functions in memory during program execution possibly reusing the memory when an object goes out of scope.

As said it depends.

Comment: This answer solely discussions extensions to C and does not answer for the base language. Also, in discussing pointer invalidation due to the pointed-to **function** being unloaded, it fails to answer the question about invalidation due to the pointer **lifetime** ending.

Comment: For the 'base' language, the memory addresses should not change throughout a process' lifetime.

Comment: OT Staates: "I think my real question is whether what the pointer points to (the function) will ever change", therefore the address of a function in memory, and this should not be subject to variable lifetime.